Create static polyline in CesiumJS
I create a GroundPolylinePrimitive with the material type PolylineDash. When I move the camera, the lines start to move. How can I make my polyline static?
My code:
let countyBorderPrimitive = new GroundPolylinePrimitive({
                    geometryInstances: new GeometryInstance({
                        geometry: new GroundPolylineGeometry({
                            positions: Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(newBorPos),
                            width: 3,
                        })
                    }),
                    show: stores.groundStore.visibleStatus,
                    appearance: new PolylineMaterialAppearance({
                        material: Material.fromType('PolylineDash', {
                            color: Color.RED,
                            dashLength: 50,
                            dashPattern: 255
                        })
                    })
                });
                cesium.scene.groundPrimitives.add(countyBorderPrimitive)

Search properties, create custom shader

can you share your code in Sandcastle?

Abbreviated URL SandCastle: http://surl.li/sknwk

the PolylineDash shader source you used：
  uniform vec4 color;
  uniform vec4 gapColor;
  uniform float dashLength;
  uniform float dashPattern;
  in float v_polylineAngle;

  const float maskLength = 16.0;

  mat2 rotate(float rad) {
    float c = cos(rad);
    float s = sin(rad);
    return mat2(
        c, s,
        -s, c
    );
  }

  czm_material czm_getMaterial(czm_materialInput materialInput)
  {
    czm_material material = czm_getDefaultMaterial(materialInput);

    vec2 pos = rotate(v_polylineAngle) * gl_FragCoord.xy;

    // Get the relative position within the dash from 0 to 1
    float dashPosition = fract(pos.x / (dashLength * czm_pixelRatio));
    // Figure out the mask index.
    float maskIndex = floor(dashPosition * maskLength);
    // Test the bit mask.
    float maskTest = floor(dashPattern / pow(2.0, maskIndex));
    vec4 fragColor = (mod(maskTest, 2.0) < 1.0) ? gapColor : color;
    if (fragColor.a < 0.005) {   // matches 0/255 and 1/255
        discard;
    }

    fragColor = czm_gammaCorrect(fragColor);
    material.emission = fragColor.rgb;
    material.alpha = fragColor.a;
    return material;
  }

the shader is to detemined the pixel on line is color or gapColor,and it decided by the pixel'position.But the shader is according to the position on screen position,not the relative position on the line.gl_FragCoord is a built-in variables of the pixel on screen position.So when the line'position on screen changed,the pattern changed too.So I recommend that maybe you can create a image material to create a static line rather than using this material .
